# supervisor gunicorn process not started on instance restart

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am trying to configure gunicorn and supervisor for Django. I have configured gunicorn and i can run the django app using gunicorn manually. Now i have tried to configure the supervisor, the issue is that gunicorn process is not being started on instance restart. If i start the app from supervisorctl manually then app will start running.
When i see status in supervisorctl, it is FATAL and stderr says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 75, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.setup(app)
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 114, in setup
    self.app.wsgi()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 66, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

**django app structure**

```
subscription-project \
  .codeintel
  .ebextensions
  .git
  .gitignore
  Makefile
  Procfile
  README.rst
  common
  config \
    __init__.py
    settings
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  djangoapps
  locale
  manage.py
  requirements
  runtime.txt
```

**subscriptionapp_gunicorn.py**

```
import multiprocessing

preload_app = True
timeout = 300
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
pythonpath = "/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscription-project"

workers = (multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
```

**upstart supervisor config** (/etc/init/supervisor.conf)

```
description     "supervisord"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

kill timeout 432000

setuid www-data
exec /subscription/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord -n --configuration /subscription/app/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

**/subscription/app/supervisor/conf.d/subscriptionapp.conf**

```
[program:subscriptionapp]

command=/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/bin/gunicorn -c /subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscriptionapp_gunicorn.py config.wsgi

user=www-data
directory=/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscription-project

environment=PORT=8000,ADDRESS=127.0.0.1,LANG=en_US.UTF-8,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.base,PATH="/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

stdout_logfile=/subscription/var/log/supervisor/subscriptionapp-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/subscription/var/log/supervisor/subscriptionapp-stderr.log
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/subscription/var/supervisor/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/subscription/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/subscription/var/supervisor/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/subscription/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///subscription/var/supervisor/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001

[include]
files = /subscription/app/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Any help to resolve the issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `config` package is not available to gunicorn. Try explicitly adding the project directory to [pythonpath](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#pythonpath) like so:

#### /subscription/app/supervisor/conf.d/subscriptionapp.conf

```
[program:subscriptionapp]

command=/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/bin/gunicorn -c /subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscriptionapp_gunicorn.py --pythonpath '/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscription-project,/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/' config.wsgi

user=www-data
directory=/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscription-project

environment=PORT=8000,ADDRESS=127.0.0.1,LANG=en_US.UTF-8,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.base,PATH="/subscription/app/subscriptionapp/venvs/subscriptionapp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

stdout_logfile=/subscription/var/log/supervisor/subscriptionapp-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/subscription/var/log/supervisor/subscriptionapp-stderr.log
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

If this helps gunicorn to "find" `config`, if may be your [gunicorn configuration file](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#config-file) is not being loaded properly. Depending on your gunicorn version, loading settings from a python module may require a special form, as in docs:

> Changed in version 19.4: Loading the config from a Python module requires the python: prefix.

Comment: pythonpath is already present in /subscription/app/subscriptionapp/subscriptionapp_gunicorn.py

Comment: I noticed; however, your ImportError still indicates an unset `pythonpath`, and using the command line argument will allow you to further understnad the problem

Comment: I have tried adding pythonpath as you suggested but still getting same issue. Any thoughts how we can debug this?

Comment: Dissect the problem into smaller parts; e.g make your supervisor conf run a test python script (can just print `sys.path`) rather then gunicorn.